# hHighstock get data for flags from json

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a series of **highstock flags** from JSON data.

JSON format: `[[timestamp, title],[timestamp, title] ...]`

and I also tried it with an associative array like `[{x: timestamp, title: "flag"}, ...]`

Is it possible to create them with JSON data or only with the given code in all highstock flag examples like:

```
'data': [{
   'title':'E',
    'x':1330560000000
 }],
```

?

Comment: Put up an example on jsfiddle.net and we can play around with it!

Comment: i dont have a json file online but this should be ok: http://jsfiddle.net/eKQcK/   i just want to get my data out of a json array

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow the Highstock [example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement) and use `data` like these:

```
data: [{
    x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
    title: 'E'
}],
```

When I do that using your example (with the synax errors fixed too!), it works.

Comment: i know that it works, when im using the highstock example, but i have to use the data from my webservice. There must be a way to get the data from php/ajax/json...

Comment: Then the answer is yes,  you can do it using data from a JSON service to get the flags data, just as you use JSON from a web service to get the regular data.  Just use getJSON() again.

Comment: thats what i have done - another [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aSkMg/1/), the second function parameter is the JSON data from my getJSON()

Comment: Make sure the `x` values are like what I have above, Date.UTC objects, and not plain numbers as you had in your original question.  It seemed to make a difference when I was jsfiddling--not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It should works properly, please take look at example:

data.json

```
    [{
            "name" : "AAPL",
            "id":"dataseries",
            "data" :[
 [1141171200000,69.10],
[1141257600000,69.61],
[1141344000000,67.72],
[1141603200000,65.48],
[1141689600000,66.31],
[1141776000000,65.66],
[1141862400000,63.93],
[1141948800000,63.19],
[1142208000000,65.68],
[1142294400000,67.32],
[1142380800000,66.23],
[1142467200000,64.31],
[1142553600000,64.66],
[1142812800000,63.99],
[1142899200000,61.81],
[1142985600000,61.67],
[1143072000000,60.16],
[1143158400000,59.96],
[1143417600000,59.51],
[1143504000000,58.71],
[1143590400000,62.33],
[1143676800000,62.75],
[1143763200000,62.72]],
            "tooltip": {
                "yDecimals": 2
            }
},{
                "type": "flags",
                "name": "Flags on axis",
                        "onSeries": "dataseries",
                "data": [{
                    "x": 1143417600000,
                    "title": "On axis"
                }],
                "shape": "squarepin"
            }]
```

and script:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series : data
    });
});
```